# Is it good practice for Keras/TensorFlow users to rely on the validation set for testing?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, model-evaluations

Some sources consider a test/train split, such as with sklearn, to be expected practice, and validation is more or less reserved for k-fold validation.

However, Keras has a somewhat different approach with its validation_split parameter.
Different sources report different things on the subject, some suggesting that this replaces test/train splitting, and it seems it should obviously not be confused with k-fold cross-validation.

Can anyone confirm or clarify what is generally expected among keras users on the subject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some additional digging I came across this [issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/1753) at the Keras source repository which seems to outline the usage and some of the confusion surrounding the nomenclature of Keras' validation set.  According to this, it appears it is correct to say that the validation set is equivalent to a test set, and the naming reflects how it is used to help assess the training process itself during training.